# Best place for annotation processing in Java WebApp

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, listener

I am creating custom annotation and would like to process it before the application starts. Basically, I would like to inject dependencies to REST services. I was thinking about `ServletContextListener` but my logic is not about servlets.

What is the best place for so-called post-construct annotation processing?

**Note:** I don't use Spring or any other frameworks and looking for an answer with minimal use of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: You have tagged this `java-ee`, which provides CDI for doing this injection for you without using any additional frameworks. Is that what you really meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your logic may not deal with servlets directly REST services (i.e. JAX-RS) are ultimately dependent on servlets.  So a `ServletContextListener` would still make sense.  You're not adding any dependencies above a servlet container which you know you're already in.